# authState(this.auth); returning empty object

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to show logged in users info (username or email, doesn't matter), but when I display is as `<a> Hello {{ user.displayName }} </a>` it displays "Hello ". After I tried displaying the full object i got [Object object]. After `console.log(this.currentUser$)` I get a prototype of Object with operator of length 1 and name = "".

Here is the code:

search.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { authState, Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private auth: Auth) {}

  currentUser$ = authState(this.auth);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.currentUser$);
  }

  doSearch(value: string) {
    console.log(`value=${value}`);
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/search/${value}`);
  }

  signOut(){
    this.authService.signOut();
  }
}
```

search.component.html

```
    <a *ngIf="currentUser$ | async as user; else loginButton" >
       Hello {{ user }} <-- to display email is {{ user.displayName }}
    </a>
    <ng-template #loginButton>
       <button class="au-btn-security" routerLink="/login">Log in</button>
       <button class="au-btn-sec" routerLink="/register">Register</button>
    </ng-template>
       <button class="au-btn-sec" (click)="signOut()">Sign Out</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

authState is supposed to emit values on sign-in and sign-out events, use user(this.auth) to get current user info